# Trouble understanding exon-chaining problem

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently trying to build a music generator. In order to improve my deal with patterns in music, I have read [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220664252_Algorithmic_compositions_based_on_discovered_musical_patterns), which states that "This algorithm (exon-chaining algorithm) can be modified to accommodate the pattern selection problem by replacing the weight of an interval with its duration".(page 9). 
However, I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of the exon-chaining problem. I have looked for this problem in many different presentations and articles but still couldn't find satisfying information. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.
Thanks in advance.